# Как вернуть строки вектора (1) как число (результат работы "sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder"), которые встречаются в другом векторе (2) как текст?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

**Есть датафрейм состоящий из 2 векторов: где 1 вектор ('cleanUrl') и 2 вектор ('code_url').**

В 1 векторе записи url, во 2 векторе записи url преобразованные в число, при помощи библиотеки *from sklearn import preprocessing*
метода *preprocessing.LabelEncoder()*

Возможным решением вижу обратное преобразование вектора 2 в текст, или преобразование вектора 1 как число.

пример файла :

```
cleanUrl,code_url
amerikan-gruzovik.ru,4590
tinatube.net,74861
sextelevizor.net,66791
ru.anysex.com,62743
www.asiamobil.ru,86865
www.chinamobil.ru,90045
ad-k.ru,2637
www.nik-store.ru,105112
video-seks.net,80108
russkoe-porno.info,63946
www.foxporns.com,94819
www.chrono24.com.ru,90117
www.wibes.ru,118283
german242.com,26297
santdom.ru,65100
treningchess.com,76231
razvedem.web-3.ru,60517
aktis-stroy.ru,3525
www.aktis-stroy.ru,85600
plot.name,56170
www.lichnycabinet.ru,100979
www.worldfishing.narod.ru,118532
sekretka.su,66123
www.a-centre.ru,85011
www.suzukirus.ru,113986
pornogl.com,57123
wmid234ru.ru,83678
hsi.ru,29794
infometer.ru,31244
www.git77.rostrud.ru,95784
www.packagetrackr.com,106632
www.tns-global.ru,115139
www.vipgroup.net,117281
www.toysrus.com,115433
moskva.wisell.ru,46046
www.shopjustice.com,111904
deti75.ru,16625
crimeacity.info,15195
baza.crimea.ua,8838
atelica-oazis.bron.me,6647
gokurort.ru,26990
mitula17.imhonet.ru,44811
foxbrest.imhonet.ru,24645
xavi.imhonet.ru,120090
ural.kp.ru,78539
spb.kp.ru,69996
pinkmarie.com,55650
geneva2015.cars.ru,26188
domodedovo.rujazi.com,18057
xn------5cdjccgu2avckptly3ad8p.xn--e1arcbfn.xn--p1ai,120241
baikalpress.ru,8328
klimovsk.mnogonado.net,35750
svet-modern.ru,72656
www.forex-kf.ru,94627
www.uniq-ip.com,116401
www.terrawoman.ua,114714
www.gorsovet.mk.ua,96192
vmr.gov.ua,81250
helpstu.su,28874
www.helpstu.su,96823
zab-nanny.ru,122892
kursak-diplom.com.ua,37838
kgu-journalist.ucoz.ru,34771
mospf.ru,46093
newdiplom.ucoz.ru,49231
www.autoezda.com,87258
referats.nashisrael.ru,60990
www.hotdiplom.ru,97129
fotorakom.com,24577
redirect.disqus.com,60900
www.sq.com.ua,113207
member.newsnet.in.ua,43580
bankomet.com.ua,8537
po4emu.ru,56252
www.po4emu.ru,107650
tric.info,76258
myotpusk.com,47714
yspehx.narod.ru,122777
vozhatiki.ru,81885
kirent.narod.ru,35483
www.festivalsearcher.com,94080
hotasianz.com.6716069.yupiromo.ru,29549
starblag.ucoz.ua,70955
www.medalbum.ru,102495
ab28ru.narod.ru,2336
diel.ks.ua,16931
aniplay.tv,5091
ugolzreniya.narod.ru,77854
vrn.vestipk.ru,81990
afg-hist.ucoz.ru,3023
www.shanson-plus.ru,111700
www.vsmolenske.ru,117854
vsetutonline.com,82254
stomatologmova.ucoz.ua,71506
xn----8sbgjprccxgonf4d1dya7b.xn--p1ai,120742
yarcube.ru,122335
www.pion.com.ru,107364
76yar.ru,1961
loveplanet-online.ru,40510
```

Ответ будет содержать не повторяющиеся строки из вектора 2 в формате датафрейм:
`[4590, 4591, 4594, 4595, 4597, 4598]` пример массива, датафрейма не знаю как.

Comment: вы хотите получить уникальные значения столбца `code_url`?

Comment: `"Возможным решением вижу обратное преобразование вектора 2 в текст, или преобразование вектора 1 как число"` - а зачем если у вас уже все URL закодированы как числа?

Comment: никак не пойму что вы хотите сделать... `LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['cleanUrl'])` - для одинаковых URL вернет одинаковые числа, поэтому я не понимаю зачем что-то обратно декодировать или кодировать опять... Может опишите вашу задачу более широко, а нетолько этот шаг?

Comment: @MaxU я хочу оставить такие значения в 'code_url', которые встречаются в 'cleanUrl'. Вы правы, решение преобразовать вектор 1 в число.

Comment: так вы уже преобразовали - или `code_url` это не результат работы `LabelEncoder`?

Comment: Эти вектора ни как между собой не взаимоссвязаны, поскольку взяты с разных датасетов. code_url результат работы LabelEncoder. 'cleanUrl' с другого датасета.

Comment: а как тогда понимать: `"во 2 векторе записи url преобразованные в число, при помощи библиотеки from sklearn import preprocessing метода preprocessing.LabelEncoder()"`? Можете привести код, где вы получили столбец `code_url`?

Comment: from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df_label_url['cod_url'])

Comment: а в чем смысл держать в одной строке DF URL и никак не связанный с ним код (скорее всего) другого URL?

Comment: Можно разделить на разные datafreim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос (в чем я совсем не уверен) вы пытаетесь закодировать URL (первый столбец) таким образом чтобы получить "правильные" коды, которые соответствовали бы кодам второго столбца (хотя коды второго столбца были получены из другого набора данных).

Это можно сделать если обучить `LabelEncoder` на полном наборе данных - т.е. ему надо скормить все возможные URL из обоих наборов данных (DataFrames).

Пример:

исходный DF:

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]:
                cleanUrl
0   amerikan-gruzovik.ru
1   amerikan-gruzovik.ru
2           tinatube.net
3           tinatube.net
4       sextelevizor.net
5          ru.anysex.com
6       www.asiamobil.ru
7      www.chinamobil.ru
8                ad-k.ru
9       www.nik-store.ru
..                   ...
12      www.foxporns.com
13   www.chrono24.com.ru
14          www.wibes.ru
15         german242.com
16            santdom.ru
17      treningchess.com
18     razvedem.web-3.ru
19        aktis-stroy.ru
20    www.aktis-stroy.ru
21             plot.name

[22 rows x 1 columns]
```

Кодируем URL:

```
In [27]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [28]: le = LabelEncoder()

In [29]: df['code_url'] = le.fit_transform(df['cleanUrl'])

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
                cleanUrl  code_url
0   amerikan-gruzovik.ru        19
1   amerikan-gruzovik.ru        19
2           tinatube.net         3
3           tinatube.net         3
4       sextelevizor.net         9
5          ru.anysex.com         6
6       www.asiamobil.ru        11
7      www.chinamobil.ru        15
8                ad-k.ru         0
9       www.nik-store.ru        13
..                   ...       ...
12      www.foxporns.com        12
13   www.chrono24.com.ru        18
14          www.wibes.ru         4
15         german242.com         5
16            santdom.ru         2
17      treningchess.com        10
18     razvedem.web-3.ru        14
19        aktis-stroy.ru         7
20    www.aktis-stroy.ru        17
21             plot.name         1

[22 rows x 2 columns]
```

Теперь возьмем другой DF:

```
In [32]: df2
Out[32]:
               cleanUrl
0          tinatube.net
1            santdom.ru
2    www.aktis-stroy.ru
3         ru.anysex.com
```

чтобы получить коды соответствующие первому DF надо воспользоваться уже обученным объектом `LabelEncoder` - использовать будем `transform()` вместо `fit_transform()` чтобы не переобучить `le` на новых данных:

```
In [33]: df2['code_url'] = le.transform(df2['cleanUrl'])

In [34]: df2
Out[34]:
               cleanUrl  code_url
0          tinatube.net         3
1            santdom.ru         2
2    www.aktis-stroy.ru        17
3         ru.anysex.com         6
```

---

Если попытаться закодировать строку, которая не встречалась при обучении (`.fit()` или `.fit_transform()`), то получим следующую ошибку:

```
In [35]: le.transform(['ru.stackoverflow.com'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-51ca5dd7c8c5> in <module>()
----> 1 le.transform(['ru.stackoverflow.com'])

~\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in transform(self, y)
    131         if len(np.intersect1d(classes, self.classes_)) < len(classes):
    132             diff = np.setdiff1d(classes, self.classes_)
--> 133             raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" % str(diff))
    134         return np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
    135

ValueError: y contains new labels: ['ru.stackoverflow.com']
```

Comment: после пойска обучения не будет.